# "CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND" in OpenCl

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl

I want to get the OpenCL device. I know that I can use the GPU.
I used this device before with n C# Wrapper for OpenCL and this still works.

```
cl_int error;
std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
error = cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
std::cout << GetError(error) << std::endl;

auto platform = platforms.front();

std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
error = platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
std::cout << GetError(error) << std::endl;

auto device = devices.front();
```

I have an AMD Vega 56.

If I print the name of the platform it just prints some unreadable characters but with no error code.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What OS? Does `clinfo` show some reasonable info? Also, what is `GetError`? It makes sense to print just error code - zero will mean success

Comment: thx for helping but it was an driver issue the amd driver somehow crased and I couldnot use opencl anymore Updated the driver and it worked again.